# How to call a VB.NET application from a remote system by Java servlets?

Tags: java, vb.net, call

I have an application in VB.NET. I want to call that application from a remote system by using Java servlets. Can anybody tell me the methods for that?

Answer (score 0):

Make the VB.NET application expose an HTTP WCF endpoint and call from Java using standard web services calls.